# Add Points to a Point Cloud with User Mouse Clicks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, 3d, three.js

I'm using Three.js to render point cloud data retrieved from a server.

For each data set, I loop over the data points and create a Three.js Vector3 object with x, y & z values corresponding to each data point. I push each of these vertices onto a list which I then pass into the vertices prop of my geometry component within my points component.

```
render() {
    this.pointCloudVertices = [];
    if (this.props.points) {
        const points = this.props.points
        for (let i = 0; i < points.x.length; i++) {
            const vertex = new THREE.Vector3();

            vertex.x = points.x[i]
            vertex.y = points.y[i]
            vertex.z = points.z[i]

            this.pointCloudVertices.push(vertex);
        }
    }
    return (<points>
        <geometry vertices={this.pointCloudVertices}/>
        <pointsMaterial
            color={ (Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215)) }
            size={ 0.2 }
        />
    </points>);
}
```

https://github.com/caseysiebel/pc-client/blob/master/src/components/PointCloud.js

I'd like the user to be able to use their mouse to add points to another point cloud (points component) by clicking inside the canvas.

I found a lot of resources pointing to the Three.js' Raycaster, but this tool seems to be more for selecting out objects already in the canvas. In my case I'd like the user to be able to click on and area in the canvas not occupied by an object, have the client work out the x, y & z coordinates of that click and then add a vertex, with those x/y/z values, to a points component (likely empty until the user adds points via this modality).

I'm a little confused as to how I will convert 2D mouse events into a 3D vertex value. If anyone knows any good resources on this subject I'd love to check them out.

Comment: "I'm a little confused as to how I will convert 2D mouse events into a 3D vertex value" `new THREE.Vector(mouseX, mouseY, 0)` would be the simplest solution, though probably not satisfying. I'd say, at this point, this is more of a design problem than math. How **do you want** this 2D plane to be converted into the 3D space? Imagine you sitting in your living room, on the sofa and pointing in some direction. Where do you want this point to be added? Especially at what depth/distance from you? How to decide this for the first point(s)? How for the later ones?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Based on you're comment, I think there are two questions here. You're right if I select a point in a 2D plane, really I'm defining a ray extending from where I sit (the camera position) along the third axis extending infinitely. The question of where I want my new point to sit along this ray is a design question. The question of how the current position of the camera and the origin defined by the data sets translates to what plane I am viewing is a mathematical one.

Comment: On the math part, the [projectionMatrix](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/cameras/Camera.projectionMatrix) of the Camera should be the one you're interrested in to determine the ray; but it's been a while that I did THREE.js

Comment: Can you have the user spin the mouse wheel to set the Z of the point in the projected ray? Perhaps the initial Z could be the average Z of existing points, or the same Z as the most recently added point.

Comment: what type of camera do you use?

Comment: looks like a "perspectiveCamera" if that answers your question: https://github.com/caseysiebel/pc-client/blob/941b833fe191adab092247a6ae9bdf208701c306/src/components/Viz.js#L103

Answer (score 1):

With [`THREE.Raycaster()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/core/Raycaster), I see several solutions:

**1.** Use the `.at()` method of the [`.ray`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/math/Ray) property. Like this:

```
raycaster.ray.at(100 + Math.random() * 150, rndPoint);
```

Here you can set the constraints for the distance from the origin of the ray, and it will look like this from your original camera:

[image: front camera view]

and how it will look like from aside:

[image: free camera view]

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/qb3240v2/) example. You can switch the lines off there.

**2.** Use the `.intersectObjects()` method. Where intersecting objects are planes of constraints. For example, we have planes in the form of a cube. When we cast a ray through them, we always intersect two planes, and the array of intersectec objects will be sorted by distance from the origin of the ray. Thus the first element in this array will be the closest plane. So, when we know it, we can take their points of intersection and sub *point1* from *point2*, getting a new vector (its length and direction). And then we'll just set a point at a random place along the vector from *point1* to *point2*:

```
intersected = raycaster.intersectObjects(planes.children);
  if (intersected.length > 0){
    var point1 = intersected[0].point;
    var point2 = intersected[1].point;
    var diff = point2.clone().sub(point1);
    var diffLength = diff.length();
    rndPoint = point1.clone().addScaledVector(diff.normalize(), Math.random() * diffLength);
    . . .
  }
```

It will look like this from the front camera:

[image: front camera view]

and from aside:

[image: free camera view]

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/ax9zc8hx/) example. Lines are switchable here too.

Or you can use [`THREE.Raycaster()` with `THREE.OrthographicCamera()`](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_cubes_ortho). Which is simplier )